# How do I set Application Configuration Mappings in IIS6 from the command line?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am rolling out .NET 4 to around 60 servers, and I need register the .mvc extension to run with ASP.NET on each server after the install.

Does anyone know a way to do this from the command line? Is it possible?

I looked at the aspnet_regiis tool, but it doesn't seem to promising past installing/uninstalling ASP.NET.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line tool in IIS6 is c:\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs.  Just run it without any parameters to get some basic help.

It's ScriptMaps that are used, and you'll just need to copy the current .aspx script map but save it with a .mvc extension.